# Send test reports to different directory using maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: junit, maven-plugin, maven-3

I want to generate my reports so I used `maven-surefire-plugin`.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.10</version>
<executions> 
<execution> 
 <id>test-reports</id> 
    <phase>install</phase> 
    <configuration> 
      <tasks> 
<junitreport todir="./reports">
<fileset dir="./reports">
<include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
</fileset>
<report format="frames" todir="./report/html"/>
</junitreport>
</tasks> 
    </configuration> 
    <goals> 
      <goal>test </goal> 
    </goals> 
  </execution> 
</executions> 
</plugin>
```

But I'm getting this error when I run maven test:

```
 Tests run: 6, Failures: 2, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
 [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 10.403s
 [INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 12 08:35:10 CEST 2011
 [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/126M
 [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-      plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project jebouquine: There are test failures.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Amira\workspace1\jebouquine\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1]       http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

When I open  `C:\Users\Amira\workspace1\jebouquine\target\surefire-reports` I find repotrts but I want them under `./reports`.

Any idea how to do it? Or is there any alternative to generate my tests reports?

Answer (score 7):

Look, here's the bottom line: you need to read more about Maven because what you have written does not make sense.  You have tried to stuff ant configuration elements into the surefire plugin config, which is not right at all.  And you have tried to bind it to the install phase, but then you are running `mvn test`.

Finally, it might help if you explained why you want them in a different directory in the first place ... there might be a better way to achieve your real goals.

However, this will fix your problem for the next 5 seconds or so:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10</version>
  <configuration>
    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/reports</reportsDirectory>
  </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

Comment: thank u but i used youre code but i still have the same error: should i use the maven-junit-report-plugin??

Comment: I thought you wanted the reports under `reports` instead of `surefire-reports`.  They should be in the right place now, aren't they?